# Растягивание картинки под размер родителя

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте!

Есть блок 700x700 и есть картинка 500x500, которая находится в блоке. Как автоматически зумровать картинку под размер блока? Т.е. она увеличится, но поместится в блоке.

Пробовал через bg-size: cover, но там теряется качество картинки. Есть варианты?

Comment: Это естественно, когда увеличиваешь картинку больше 100% получаешь мыло.

Comment: @Crantisz где-то я уже это слышал)

Comment: это говорил внутри Здравый Смысл

Answer (score 1):

Без потери качества всё равно не обойтись, это логично. Можно немного смягчить изображение с помощью

```
background-size: cover;
image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;
image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
image-rendering: crisp-edges;
-ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
  width: 100%; /* ширина картинки */
  height: auto; /* высота картинки */
}
```

Comment: всё равно теряет качество

Comment: на примере jsfiddle можно?

Comment: Не может картинка которую с 500х растянули на 700х не потерять в качестве, это не ее размер, было бы странно если любая мелкая картинка растягивалась на любой размер и не теряла бы при этом в качестве)

Comment: исключение векторное изображение =)